# I'm using DropDownMultiSelect, where I'm getting A RenderFlex overflowed for dropdown values

Tags: flutter, ng-dropdown-multiselect

I'm using

```
DropDownMultiSelect
```

there I'm getting A RenderFlex overflowed error for the dropdown values

```
child: DropDownMultiSelect(
  onChanged: (c){
    setState(() {
      selectedColors = ["","","","",""];
      initialColor = c;
      for(int i=0; i<initialColor.length; i++){
        selectedColors[i] = initialColor[i];
      }
    });
  },
  options: colorList,
  selectedValues: initialColor,
    whenEmpty: "Select Color",
),
```

this is what I tried,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you used `multiselect` package:

change your `multiselect: ^0.0.7` in `pubspec.yaml` file to:

```
multiselect:
    git:
      url: https://github.com/XuannThucc/multiselect
      ref: 8b1dc71ae4982db4c37d477bb8021ac71badd595
```

then run `flutter pub get` and rebuild;

Comment: thank you, it's working, but instead of calling your url I added states_builder package in pubspec yaml and copied your multiselect file in my original project